# How to select DISTINCT(username) and MAX(timestamp) from access log - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, distinct

I have a log file for an application that shows two columns, username and timestamp. I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL query to show only the last time each user logged in.

This is the query I have put together so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, MAX(timestamp) FROM log
GROUP BY username, timestamp;
```

Unfortunately, this is still giving me multiple username entries, each with a distinct time. Any tips on how to just show the last timestamp for each user?

I'm still new to SQL so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `group by`:

```
SELECT username, MAX(timestamp)
FROM log
GROUP BY username;
```

However, if you want all the information from the `log` record, `DISTINCT ON` is a better choice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (username) l.*
FROM log
ORDER BY username, timestamp DESC;
```

You use of `SELECT DISTINCT` leads me to suspect that this might be what you want.

Comment: Okay. Good tip. I'll try that as well and see what works better. Thanks again.